# Uploading a folder to Google Drive

Tags: python, google-api, pydrive

I am trying to upload a folder to Google Drive but after reading and doing some research it seems it is not so straight as I thought.
I tried to check pydrive, but this gives only the opportunity to create a file, or to upload an existing file. What if I want to upload a whole folder?

Comment: do you mean upload the folder itself or all the files inside the folder? :)

Comment: The folder itself with all the files inside

Comment: ok, in that case: read in the files in the folder on your client and loop over them, uploading them one by one. Pydrive doens't have (as far as I know) an option to upload a folder itself. However: pydrive is 'just' a module which makes using googleapiclient a bit easier to use, maybe googleapiclient has an option to help you further if looping is no option for you.